# Drawing a diagram instead of image

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Is it possible to draw a diagram of this image, which is very simple:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What is the function of the plot on the right?

Comment: I never used latex to draw diagrams, on the right there is a simple sinusoidal signal decaying

Comment: -1 for no MWE. Please show us what you have tried so far. Because, this is not a `just-do-it-for-me` site.

Comment: @Raaja Although this question deserves closure, I don't think this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick proposal, as I am currently in free time.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={draw,minimum width=1cm}]
    \path (0,0) node[left] (m) {$M$};
    \path (-3,0) node (p) {$P$};
\end{scope}
\draw (m) -- (p) node[midway,fill=white] {$E$} node[midway,below=.5cm] {$t_1$};
\draw plot[smooth,samples=100,domain=0:2.5] (\x,{exp(-2*\x)*(sin(deg(50*\x)))});
\node at (1.5,{-.5cm-.6666em}) {$t_2$};
\node at (1.5,.3) {$D$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]